# Ranking rows according to id's mysql

Tags: mysql

I've the following query.

```
SET @rownum := 0;
SELECT result.rank, result.postid FROM (                    
                SELECT CASE @rownum 

                WHEN 5 THEN  @rownum:=1 ELSE @rownum:=@rownum + 1  END AS rank
                    ,c.postid

                FROM comments c
                ORDER BY c.postid DESC
                ) as result
```

It returns me the result in the following form.

```
      rank               postid
    ---------------------------------
      1                    199
      2                    199
      3                    199
      4                    199
      5                    198
      1                    198
      2                    198
      3                    198
      4                    198
      5                    198
      6                    198
```

Now I wanted to update this query such that ranks are specified according to postid.postid 199 will be ranked from 1 to 4 and as soon as it identifies that a new postid has appeared it should again rank it from 1 to whatever number of records that id contains.

`I want the count of rank for each postid to start from 1 and goto the number of times that postid is appearing.`

**Edit:**

@lieven it's still giving a problem check this image.[image]

As you can see the post `172` finishes but the rank still continues

Comment: Do you have a primary key on `Comments`?

Comment: yes i've four columns in the comments table. `comments,userid,postid,tempid(primary key)`

Comment: How to sort records in group? Which sould be first, second...?

Comment: I want the result in the exact same form as i've mentioned above but the only thing that i want is that when a new postid starts the rank should get reset to 1 and increments to the amount of time that postid is appearing and when again the new postid will appear lets say 197 after 198 then the rank will again get set to 1 and increment the number of times 197 is appearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following statement but the performance will be abissimal on any large table.

For each record, a subselect is executed that get's the `count` as a rank for equal `postid`'s where the primary key is less or equal to that of the current record. If you return 100 records, in essence 101 statements would have been executed.

**SQL Statement (slow)**

```
>     SELECT c.postid    
>            , (SELECT COUNT(*) 
>               FROM   comments 
>               WHERE  postid = c.postid 
>                      AND tempid <= c.tempid
>              ) AS rank
>     FROM   comments c
>     ORDER BY
>            c.postid
```

**SQL Statement (fast(er))**

```
>     SET @rank := 1;
>     
>     SELECT  c1.postid
>             , CASE WHEN c1.postid= c2.postid 
>               THEN @rank := @rank + 1 
>               ELSE @rank := 1 
>               END AS Rank
>     FROM    (
>               SELECT  c.postid
>                       , @rownum1 := @rownum1 + 1 AS rownum
>               FROM    comments c, (SELECT @rownum1 := 1) r       
>               ORDER BY
>                       c.postid
>             ) c1
>             LEFT OUTER JOIN (
>               SELECT  c.postid
>                       , @rownum2 := @rownum2 + 1 AS rownum
>               FROM    comments c, (SELECT @rownum2 := 1) r       
>               ORDER BY
>                       c.postid
>             ) c2 ON c2.postid = c1.postid AND c2.rownum = c1.rownum - 1
>      ORDER BY
>             c1.postid
```

Comment: that's exactly what i need but as you know it is a comments table and it will fill in very quickly into a huge dataset.So don't you think it will create `performance` problems for me in the future so is a better solution possible?

Comment: @Mj1992 - I have added another version that should prove to be much faster on large tables.

Comment: rank is not incrementing it is set to `1` in the whole result.In your faster query.

Comment: @Mj1992 - I added an order by, can you verify if it makes any difference?

Comment: @Mj1992 - MySQL is not my forté *(it's showing:)* but perhaps it's the reuse of a variable with the same name that is giving problems. I have altered the statement to cater for this. Can you again verify?

Comment: @Mj1992 - I finally took the time to test this in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6ced4/10). The only thing that was missing was the assignment to `@rownum(12) :=` `(io @rownum(12) =)`.

Comment: @Mj1992 - No matter what [I try](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/99111/1), I can't make it **not** work. If you can reproduce this behavior by changing the fiddle I made, I'm more than willing to take another look at this.

Comment: thnx alot for your help I'll try find out and solve this problem by myself.You've helped alot thnx for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can order by multiple fields:

```
ORDER BY c.postid DESC, c.rank
```

The first one has highest priority.

Comment: can you write me the complete query?

Comment: Can't test it right now, but try just rank, and not c.rank. Forgot you nested selects.